# Remove all files from folder SVN using Powershell

Tags: powershell, svn

I know this question may sound like a duplicate but I feel like it's slightly different.
I am trying to remove all the files from a folder from svn using Powershell

```
svn delete 'https://someurl/svn/test/Application'
```

Would delete the entire folder, but I want to delete the file(s)/subfolder(s) inside this "application" folder.

I have tried doing something like  svn delete `https://someurl/svn/test/Application/*.*` or *.zip for the zip files but none of that seems to work.

I've been googling for solutions but most of those question have a physical path involved in their answer. The problem is that my folder is not on the same path/directory than my colleagues are using.

Comment: Is it possible to loop through all items ans delete them one by one?

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1**

You can delete all objects in your local WC's related directory and commit this change

**Way 2**

You can't use *any* wildcard in `svn del` parameter, but you can enumerate all parameters in two ways

- Space-separated URLs (beware of common string-length) like `svn del URL1 URL2 URL3`
- Using `--targets FILE` options, there FILE contains all objects for deletion (newline-separated, AFAICR). And FILE is result of ordinary `svn ls https://someurl/svn/test/Application > FILE`